# Spring Caching Issue

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

I am following the Spring Caching tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) and have run into an issue when I tried expanding it.

I've extended the `Book` Object to include an `author` property:

```
public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private Author author;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, Author author) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Now when I search for a `book` that has the same `author`, I would imagine that it would hit the cache once that `author` was saved, however my sample code is proving otherwise.

Here is my `main` class:

```
   public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info(".... Fetching books");
        log.info("isbn-1234 -->");
        log.info(bookRepository.getByIsbn("isbn-1234").toString());
        log.info("isbn-4567 -->");
        log.info(bookRepository.getByIsbn("isbn-4567").toString());
    }
```

Here are my Repos:

```
public class SimpleBookRepository implements BookRepository {

    private AuthorRepository authorRepo;

    String[] authors = new String[]{"Test User"};
    Random random = new Random();


    public SimpleBookRepository(AuthorRepository authorRepo) {
        this.authorRepo = authorRepo;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames={"books","authors"},key="#isbn")
    public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
        simulateSlowService();
        //int rNum = random.nextInt(authors.length);
        Author a = authorRepo.getByName(authors[0]); // <-- Should get from cache!  Why isnt it!
        return new Book(isbn, "Some book", a);
    }

    private void simulateSlowService() {
        try {
            long time = 5000L;
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}


public class SimpleAuthorRepository implements AuthorRepository {

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames="authors", key="#name")
    public Author getByName(String name) {
        simulateSlowService();
        return new Author(name);
    }

    private void simulateSlowService() {
        System.out.println("Getting from DB");
        try {
            long time = 5000L;
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

When I run my example my output indicates that the author isn't being pulled from the cache:

```
INFO 6944 --- [main] config.Application: .... Fetching books
INFO 6944 --- [main] config.Application: isbn-1234 -->
Getting from DB
INFO 6944 --- [main] config.Application: Book [isbn=isbn-1234, title=Some book, author=models.Author@15587018]
INFO 6944 --- [main] config.Application: isbn-4567 -->
Getting from DB
INFO 6944 --- [main] config.Application: Book [isbn=isbn-4567, title=Some book, author=models.Author@15587018]
```

Any idea's as to why it's not hitting the cache when getting the author?  I'm stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your trace both book instances refer to the same author instance `models.Author@15587018`. So what you see in logs is book is not being cached, which is ok, because you use different `isbn`

Comment: One would think it should be though.  I do not understand why the author object would not be cached within the `AuthorRepository`, since they have the same name and that is my cache key.

Comment: It is cached, otherwise `new Author(name)` would produce different instances. Are you sure you do not have `Getting from DB` in SimpleBookRepository? The code you have shown can't produce such output

Comment: Yes, I am positive I do not have that text in the `SimpleBookRepository`.

Comment: Then behavior is weird indeed. You get inside `getByName` method second time and then return result is ignored in favor of previously cached author.

Comment: If the author was being cached, it would never make it into `simulateSlowService` and print that statement.  I'm stumped as to whats happening